# I need to make a subscribe on a topic which has the return to image the camera kinect own turtlebot2

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, kinect, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm Using turtlebot2 in my research, and I need to make a subscribe on a topic which has the return to image the camera kinect own turtlebot, or cloud points captured by it, I wonder what the topic should I use in specific and how can I make him subscribe !! I'll be passing these images to an interface that I am creating in real time if tivrem a hint of how to do also the subscriber to my interface would be grateful!

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198597/i-need-to-make-a-subscribe-on-a-topic-which-has-the-return-to-image-the-camera-kinect-own-turtlebot2/) by [leobber](https://answers.ros.org/users/20424/leobber/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-11-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [leobber](https://answers.ros.org/users/20424/leobber/) on 2014-11-30**:
image of camera and laserscan!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you take a look here: [3dsensor](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_bringup/Tutorials/hydro/3D%20Visualisation)?, this provides all the nodes that publishes all the info related to the Kinect camera.

---

Originally posted by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) with karma: 82 on 2015-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0